# Javascript handling  a collapsible div  and child divs

Tags: javascript

I have a collapsible div implemented in js, the function of which is show/hide it's child divs etc.

So when you click on it, it toggles the div's disappear. Something similar to a tree view

What i want to do is that, i should be able to select the data in the child divs, but the problem is. when I click on the child divs the parent divs disappears as the onclick gets trigger i guess.

Please suggest how to should i achieve this. So my goal is to toggle a div's display which enclosing child divs,  but if you select something or highlight something in child div the parent div shouldn't collapse etc.

Please see code below.

```
                        <html>
                <head>
                    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                    <title>Data</title>
                    <style>
                        #container {
                            clear: both;
                            width: 400px;
                            margin: 0 0;
                            border: none;
                        }

                        #row {
                            clear: both;
                            width: 100%;
                            border: none;
                        }

                        #column {
                            border: double #aca899;
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            width: 402px;
                        }       

                        #columnHeader p {
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            text-align: center;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 20px;
                            padding-top: 2px;
                            font-size: 8.0pt;
                            font-family: Verdana;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            color: black;
                            text-decoration: underline;
                            border: 1px ridge #aca899;
                        }

                        #subSectionHeader {
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            width: 50%;
                            font-size: 7.5pt;
                            font-family: Arial;
                            background-color: #DBA083;
                            border: 1px ridge #aca899;
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            padding: 1px;
                        }       


                        #label {
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            width: 50%;
                            font-size: 7.5pt;
                            font-family: Arial;
                            background-color: #F2CF93;
                            border: 1px ridge #aca899;
                            padding: 1px 1px 1px 11px;
                        }       


                        #Value {
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            width: 50%;
                            font-size: 7.5pt;
                            font-family: Arial;
                            background-color: #DDDDDD;
                            border: 1px ridge #aca899;
                            padding: 1px;
                        }           

                    </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               function switchMenu(cur, e) {
               var obj = e.target || e.srcElement; //works on IE and FF
               var childDiv = cur.id + 'Child';


                    if (obj.parentNode.id != childDiv) {
                        var el = document.getElementById(childDiv);
                        if (el.style.display != "none") {
                            el.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        else {
                            el.style.display = '';
                        }
                    }
                }

              </script>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <div id="container">

                        <div style="margin-top: 15px;"></div>
                        <div id="row">
                            <div id="column">
                            <div id="abc" onclick="switchMenu(this, event)">

                                <div id="columnHeader"><p>Section 1</p></div>                   

                                <div id="subSectionHeader"><p>Some Label I</p></div> <div id="subSectionHeader"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                                <div id="abcChild">
                                <div id="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div id="value"><p>Value</p></div>                  
                                <div id="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div id="value"><p>Value</p></div>                  
                                <div id="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div id="value"><p>Value</p></div>                  
                                </div>
                                </div> <!--abc-->

                                <!--cde -->
                                <div id="cde" onclick="switchMenu(this, event)">
                                <div id="subSectionHeader"><p>Some Label II</p></div>   <div id="subSectionHeader"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                                <div id="cdeChild">
                                <div id="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div id="value"><p>Value</p></div>
                                <div id="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div id="value"><p>Value</p></div>
                                <div id="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div id="value"><p>Value</p></div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--cde -->
                            </div>  

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Your suggestion and help will be appreciated 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not perform action if the click is performed on the child div.
Update:

The edited structure is different as you have p inside div.  I've modified the code to work with the new structure.  Note that id must be unique. Your css messes up the layout and causing the code to fail. The code works if you take out your css.

This will be much simpler if you use jquery.

Code updated to include suggestion by RobG

Update2:
Fixing bug in findParent and more robust.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Data</title>
        <style>
                        #container {
                            clear: both;
                            width: 400px;
                            margin: 0 0;
                            border: none;
                        }

                        .row {
                            clear: both;
                            width: 100%;
                            border: none;
                        }

                        .column {
                            border: double #aca899;
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            width: 402px;
                        }       

                        .columnHeader p {
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            text-align: center;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 20px;
                            padding-top: 2px;
                            font-size: 8.0pt;
                            font-family: Verdana;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            color: black;
                            text-decoration: underline;
                            border: 1px ridge #aca899;
                        }

                        .subSectionHeader {
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            width: 50%;
                            font-size: 7.5pt;
                            font-family: Arial;
                            background-color: #DBA083;
                            border: 1px ridge #aca899;
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            padding: 1px;
                        }       


                        .label {
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            width: 50%;
                            font-size: 7.5pt;
                            font-family: Arial;
                            background-color: #F2CF93;
                            border: 1px ridge #aca899;
                            padding: 1px 1px 1px 11px;
                        }       


                        .value {
                            float: left;
                            clear: none;
                            width: 50%;
                            font-size: 7.5pt;
                            font-family: Arial;
                            background-color: #DDDDDD;
                            border: 1px ridge #aca899;
                            padding: 1px;
                        }          
        </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function switchMenu(cur, e) {
    var obj = e.target || e.srcElement; //works on IE and FF
    var childDiv = cur.id + 'Child';

    if (obj.className.toLowerCase() != "nocollapse" && isInCollapsible(obj)) {
        var el = document.getElementById(childDiv);
        el.style.display = el.style.display != "none" ? "none" : "";
    }
}

function isInCollapsible(obj) {
    return findParent(obj, "div", "nocollapse") ? false : true;
}

function findParent(obj, type, name) {
    if (obj.parentNode)
        if (obj.parentNode.tagName && obj.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == type && obj.parentNode.className.toLowerCase() == name)
            return obj.parentNode;
        else
            return findParent(obj.parentNode, type, name);
    else
        return null;
}

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <div style="margin-top: 15px;"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                <div id="abc" onclick="switchMenu(this, event)">

                    <div class="columnHeader"><p>Section 1</p></div>                   

                    <div class="subSectionHeader"><p>Some Label I</p></div> <div class="subSectionHeader"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                    <div id="abcChild" class="noCollapse">
                    <div class="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div class="value"><p>Value</p></div>                  
                    <div class="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div class="value"><p>Value</p></div>                  
                    <div class="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div class="value"><p>Value</p></div>                  
                    </div>
                    </div> <!--abc-->

                    <!--cde -->
                    <div id="cde" class="parent" onclick="switchMenu(this, event)">
                    <div class="subSectionHeader"><p>Some Label II</p></div>   <div class="subSectionHeader"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                    <div id="cdeChild" class="noCollapse">
                    <div class="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div class="value"><p>Value</p></div>
                    <div class="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div class="value"><p>Value</p></div>
                    <div class="label"><p>Label</p></div>  <div class="value"><p>Value</p></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--cde -->
                </div>  

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 - pretty much exactly what I was going to post. An alternative to using id is to put a class on either the child or parent divs and test for that. The style can be toggled using: `el.style.display = el.style.display == 'none'? '' : 'none';`

Comment: It should work in IE8.  What is your IE version?  And is there any error message?

Comment: I have severl div of fieldn and valuen  and there are n div and n respective child div. Now when i expand the parent div and select something in the child div the parent div disappears/toggles/hides.

Comment: Add the html structure to your original question.

Comment: Jules. Thanks for your reply I have updated the question, now if you try you will see what i mean. Jules and RobG thanks to both for looking into this, appreciate your time.

Comment: If i try to select/hightlight a row either under Some Label I
or Some Label II, the respective parent collapses which it shouldn't. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jules, I want to do this in simple javascript, i know jquery will do great, but my requirement is simple js. I tried your suggestion but looks it's still working when i put this js in the html code i have provided in the question, Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong, is it working for you. Please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm. Jules, Thank you very much for your help and time in answering the question, really appreciate it :).